# Beautiful soup deletes part of XML code, how to fix it?

Tags: python, xml, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I use BeautifulSoup in order to analyze XML file, specifically to calculate the number of references in wikipedia article, here is the part of the code which cause the problem:

```
        soup = BeautifulSoup(proc_string, 'html.parser')

        # find all <ref> tags
        for ref_tag in soup.find_all('ref'):
            # replace the <ref> tag with the special combination of symbols
            ref_tag.replace_with('[XXR]')

        output_string = str(soup)
```

For some reason, at some articles it drops the most part of the XML code.
What might be the issue?

I tried to get references with re.sub, substituting reference tag with a specific string, but it also has some limitations.

Comment: You're using an HTML parser for an XML file. See https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#id15

Comment: As suggested, use an xml parser instead. Also, if the XML is invalid then beautifulsoup could be using a recover option and dropping the broken part. Try using `lxml`